# Bend Grid in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, grids, latex, mathematics

I'm trying to create a figure like the following:
[image]

I want to be able to convert it to Tikz code (it's for some math notes) so I'm trying to replicate it on Inkscape first. The problem is I'm very new to Inkscape, so I don't really know how to proceed and I haven't found a clear explanation on how I could achieve this.

I managed to make the grid and found a *bend* function that allows me to do this
[image]

But as it can be noted, the bending is not really symmetric, plus I don't know how to bend the grid horizontally.

How should I proceed? Is Inkscape the right software to replicate this?
Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: You can't get the exact shapes obtained using conformal mappings. You have at least two options: (1) draw the transformation in a plotting software (e.g Matplotlib or any other software), or (2) create an Inkscape extension that does the transformation (It's not that hard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way in Inkscape to distort this exactly as the example shown using the default path effects available.

If you are merely trying to recreate the shape, one possibility is to redraw it manually using the original image as a guide. You can also use a clone in Inkscape so that the shapes and curves are reflected symmetrically.

Anyway, here are the basic steps

1. Rotate the image, and line it up with a vertical guide, so that you can redraw it symmetrically. Dim the opacity and lock the image in the Objects panel.
2. With the Bézier tool, using the Spiro Path option, create half of the outside shape.

[image]

3. Group the shape, and create a clone, reflect it and move it into position using snapping

[image]

4. Double click the original group to enter into it.
5. Start drawing the other internal curves with the Bézier tool, and they will be reflected automatically by the reflected clone.

[image]